# log4j configurations for non web application

Tags: spring, logging, log4j

I've create a simple maven application and using log4j logger. My application is not a WEB application. I've tried to copy log4j.properties everywhere in java folder and everywhere across a project but still getting following error. Could you suggest how can I fix it?

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

log4j.properties

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\logging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `log4j.properties` file should be in a dirctory or JAR file that is on the classpath at runtime.

If you have a Maven project with the standard Maven project directory layout, then put the file in the directory `src\main\resources` - that way, Maven should put it in the right place for you when you compile your project.

Comment: I guess you are right! Works fine! All I needed to do is just create a resource folder and add build-resource tag in maven. Thanks!